# Using InteractiveBrowserCredential to authenticate to Azure Key Vault on production won't work

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, credentials, azure-keyvault

I want to read a secret from Azure Key Vault from my ASP.NET web application. In order to do that I don't want to authenticate the application (service principal), but the individual users (user principal). From all the possible credential types, I've concluded the best one to achieve this is
InteractiveBrowserCredential:

*DefaultAzureCredential
ManagedIdentityCredential

EnvironmentCredential

ClientSecretCredential

CertificateCredential

UserPasswordCredential

DeviceCodeCredential

**InteractiveBrowserCredential***

Here's my code:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
string password = secret.Value;
```

This works well on localhost - I get prompted for my Azure AD user and password, and I have access to the vault. However, I notice this is not my default browser but a IIS Express worker process instead.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN4ux.png)

When running this same code on production, I get the following error:

> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException:
> InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: **Showing a modal
> dialog box or form when the application is not running in
> UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation.** Specify the
> ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
> notification from a service application. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException

Afaik it should be opening a browser, not a modal dialog. Can someone help my understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, your hosting environment does not support `UserInteractive` model and it cannot open a modal dialog box or form automatically. But when we use the `InteractiveBrowserCredential` to do auth, the running environment should be able to open a modal dialog box or form automatically then we can do auth. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential?view=azure-dotnet).